# Backup and Restore

Tags: backup, restore

I want to do some testing for later use in our environment.

I have never performed a backup and restore before so I have quite a few doubts and confusions.

Before restoring, I have the option to set my content database, via central admin, to offline or even to remove it. Do I have to remove it or SharePoint will understand if I overwrite the current content database with a backup?

In the backup netBackup created we have some databases divided in one mdf and three ndfs, does that make any difference to SharePoint?

What measures should I take on the SharePoint site to make sure everything goes smooth?

Comment: Would you like to backup the whole farm? Just one web app? Just a Site Collection?

Comment: I want to test and document all scenarios. Is there a better place to start?